# How to add a class based on the cellData Key in createdCell callback in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a requirement to add a class based on the column Key in the cell in data tables. I have tried using `createdCell` callback but it contains the cell data but not the cell data source which contains the key.

```
columnDefs: [
            {
              targets: '_all',
              createdCell: function(cell, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                if(Object.keys(modifiedColumns[row]).length){
                  console.log(col, cellData);
                }
              }
            }
          ],
```

Here, I have keys of the cell in modifiedColumns for each row on which I need to add class.

These keys would be different for each row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the render function.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
    }
  } ]
} );
```

you can add classes here also.
more info from this [link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

Comment: I want to add class-based on the data key instead of the data value and this dataKey may vary for each row.

Answer (score 0):

**Objective**:

To add class names to the cells in each column, where the cell names are provided in an array. In your example, the array is called `modifiedColumns`. I assume it looks something like this:

```
var modifiedColumns = ['zero_class', 'one_class', 'two_class'];
```

So, in this case, all the cells in column index zero (i.e the first column) need to have `zero_class` added as a class name:

```
<td class="zero_class">...</td>
```

**Approach**:

To add class names to your table's `<td>` tags, you can use the DataTables `node()` function.

To know what the column index is for a specific `<td>` tag, you can use the DataTables `cells().every()` function.

We can combine these as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var modifiedColumns = ['zero_class', 'one_class', 'two_class'];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    // your initialization here
  } );

  for (var i = 0; i < modifiedColumns.length; i++) {
    table.cells().every( function (rowIdx, colIdx) {
      if (colIdx < modifiedColumns.length) {
        $(this.node()).addClass( modifiedColumns[colIdx] );
      }
    } );
  }

} );

</script>
```

**Notes:**

We assign the table to a variable: `var table = $('#example').DataTable( {`.

We use that variable in a separate `for` loop, following (and outside of) the table definition.

The `every` function has access to the row index and column index for each cell - so we use that to look up the required class name from our `modifiedColumns` array.

You cannot use the `render` function to do this, as that function only provides access to the data inside a cell - and not to the cell (i.e. the node) itself.

Comment: well, I thought of this solution also, but in my case, the values in the modified columns are not in order of table cells of a row.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Can you update your question and clarify with an example? What does the data in `modifiedColumns` look like? What is the relationship between a DataTable column index and the data in your `modifiedColumns` variable?